# Knockout applyBindings Error

Tags: knockout.js, durandal, sammy.js

I have a SPA using DurandalJS and KnockoutJS. On my initial page I allow for the clicking of an item and then I load the secondary page for that item. This is how I access the secondary page:

```
var goToDetails = function (selectedDailyLog) {

        var url = '#/dailylog/' + selectedDailyLog.id();

        //durandal/plugins/router is sammy.js

        router.navigateTo(url);

    };
```

On the secondary page I am attempting to call ko.applyBindings and I continually get the following error:

**Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: router is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: router.visibleRoutes**

Here is the javascript for the secondary page:

```
define(['config', 'durandal/system', 'services/logger', 'services/dataservice'],
function (config, system, logger, dataservice) {

    var owners = ko.observableArray();
    var selectedOwner = ko.observable();
    var dailyLog = ko.observable({ started: 'one' });
    var routeCriteria;

    //#region Internal Methods
    function activate(routeData) {      

        routeCriteria = routeData;
        dataservice.getOwners(owners);

        logger.log('Daily Log Activated with Id: ' + routeData.id.toString(), null, 'dailylog', true);

        return true;
    }

    var vm = {
        activate: activate,
        title: 'Daily Log',
        owners: owners,
        selectedOwner: selectedOwner,
        dailyLog:dailyLog
    };
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
    return vm;
```

});

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that jumps out in the example above. First and foremost in a Durandal app there's no reason to call `ko.applyBindings(vm)` on your own as this is covered by  Durandal's [composition system](http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-Composition/). 
Second the activate function returns true, which is allowed if `dataservice.getOwners(owners)` is a synchronous operation otherewise you'd have to make sure that you return a promise instead.

Let's take a look what happens when ko.applybinding(vm) runs and produces the error message. When running ko.applyBinding without a second parameter it tries to bind the vm against the whole DOM. This clashes on the first occurrence of a property that is not defined in the vm. e.g. the default starter template has a navigation section in shell.html or nav.html e.g. https://github.com/dFiddle/dFiddle-1.2/blob/gh-pages/App/samples/shell.html#L4

```
<div>
    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" data-bind="attr: { href: router.visibleRoutes()[0].hash }">
                <i class="icon-home"></i>
                <span>Durandal</span>
            </a>
```

In the example the returned vm doesn't have a router defined therefore the system produces an error.

```
var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Daily Log',
    owners: owners,
    selectedOwner: selectedOwner,
    dailyLog:dailyLog
};
// ko.applyBindings(vm); // Do NOT call applyBinding in a Durandal app
return vm;
```

But as said above your just seeing the symptoms of a call that shouldn't have been made in the first place. 
You might want to take a look at samples like https://github.com/RainerAtSpirit/Durandal-Fiddle or https://github.com/johnpapa/PluralsightSpaJumpStartFinal to learn more about Durandal's building principles.

Answer (score 0):

I probably means that the view is looking for route data to bind some navigation links to. In the code you posted you don't return the route object.

I'm not sure how your application is set up but this is something that could help:

```
define(
[
    'config', 
    'durandal/system', 
    'services/logger', 
    'services/dataservice', 
    'durandal/plugins/router'
],
function (config, system, logger, dataservice, router) {

... your code here ...

var vm = {
    activate: activate,
    title: 'Daily Log',
    owners: owners,
    selectedOwner: selectedOwner,
    dailyLog:dailyLog,
    router: router
};
ko.applyBindings(vm);
return vm;
```